# Bash, pipe output to command and get error code

Tags: pipe, ksh

I'm trying to fetch an xml using a soap call with curl, please see below. As you can see I pipe the output of an echo-command into the -d parameter of curl. We have an old version of curl, therefore we cannot use the --data-urlencode function. Now my solution works, however I don't know how to get the errorcode of the curl command. Please help!

```
$HEADER="<xml>this is my header I want to post</xml>"
echo $HEADER | curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -H 'SOAPAction:https://blabla' -d @- -o output.xml -X POST https://blablabla
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the error code from the previous command in bash through the variable '$?'